# How can I tell emacs to ignore the XF86AudioFoo keys?

Tags: keystrokes, x11

Using 24.5.1 on OpenBSD 5.9. OpenBSD's sndiod listens for XF86AudioLowerVolume and the rest, but if emacs is running in graphical mode with either GTK2 or GTK3 (I haven't tried lucid/AWT, but I will if somebody thinks that will make a difference) instead of sndiod receiving that keypress, emacs writes "<XF86AudioLowerVolume> is undefined" in the echo area and sndiod never receives the key, so if I want to change the volume I have to un-focus emacs (which can be problematic in a tiling wm). It works fine in terminal mode, presumably because the controlling terminal knows to ignore the event.

Is there a way to tell emacs to ignore certain keypresses when it has focus?